# Reading CSV file in stored procedure and compare with existing table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a CSV file, and would like to do a comparison with an existing table to make sure that the fields are updated correctly. *(Someone else did the update of the table, I'm just checking if it's updated correctly)*

I understand that I can load the csv into a table before doing the comparison but would like to explore if there's any other way to READ the CSV without loading it into a new table.

I'm planning to create a stored procedure to do the comparison, would like to know if it's possible to READ the CSV in stored procedure and do the comparison with the table directly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot read a csv file in a mysql stored procedure without loading into a table with mysql's standard functionality.

The only option you have is to write or find a [compiled user defined function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-loadable-function.html) that can do this operation or you need to modify mysql's source code.

These options are probably an overkill, so you are better off doing this reconciliation check in an external programming language.

Comment: *you cannot read a csv file in a mysql stored procedure without loading into a table with mysql's standard functionality.* Formally this is not true. OP may create a table with `Engine = CSV` and access CSV data like it is imported. OP may load CSV into variable using `LOAD_FILE()` and parse it to the rowset. There exists more variants.

Comment: @Akina csv table engine cannot be used to open an existing file. Load_file() loads a csv file into a string and mysql does not have a rowset data type.

Comment: CSV table body may be replaced with your CSV file if the structure and the amount of rows matched. LOAD_FILE() may be used in CTE for to load the file content into TEXT column which then may be parsed in the next recursive CTE.

Comment: @Akina to replace the csv table's file you need to stop mysql. Mysql's string functions are not really suitable for parsing a csv structure, but if you think you have a better solution, provide an answer.